# Change default status of entry publication (Lightswitch 'Status')

Tags: entries, status, lightswitch

When I write an article and save it, I want to verify my text. 
I don't want publish my article immediately.
If I'm tired, I sometimes forget to disable the Lightswitch 'Status'.
So, how can I disable it by default?

Comment: Feature requested : http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/9328431-configure-new-entry-default-status-to-draft

Answer (score 7):

If you're using a Craft Client or Craft Pro, you can save your entry as a draft and review it later.

[image]

This isn't foolproof either. If you wanted to really try to restrict yourself, you could set up another user account that doesn't have privileges to "Publish live changes."

[image]

But again, this would require either a Craft Client or Craft Pro license.

Answer (score 3):

As of Craft 2.6.2771, sections now have a “Default Entry Status” section.

Answer (score 1):

There's no setting to define a default master status for entries, but there's locale specific statuses that can be set to a default in the section's settings.

This requires Craft Pro and more than one locale configured though.

Answer (score 1):

In the Admin CP navigate to Settings -> Sections and choose the entry type you want to change;
In the Site Settings table, toggle the Default Status lightswitch to off.